# How do I rotate a parabola around its origin?

Tags: math

I've been messing around making a golf game. I can draw the balls' predicted motion parabola using kinematic equations easily enough. That is I have isolated the x, y and z components of its motion (it is a 3D parabola). Now I am trying to work out how to draw this predictor line when I rotate the parabola. I have been successful doing this when the z component equals 0 and the parabola is effectively a straight line. I have run into difficulty when there is a z component to the motion.

I have been using this piece of code to find the equation of the z component parabola knowing three points on the parabola (one of them is always (0,0) one is the vertex and the last (max distance, 0)):

```
public void CalcParabolaVertex(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3, out double xv, out double yv)
    {
        double denom = (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x3) * (x2 - x3);
        double A = (x3 * (y2 - y1) + x2 * (y1 - y3) + x1 * (y3 - y2)) / denom;
        double B = (x3 * x3 * (y1 - y2) + x2 * x2 * (y3 - y1) + x1 * x1 * (y2 - y3)) / denom;
        double C = (x2 * x3 * (x2 - x3) * y1 + x3 * x1 * (x3 - x1) * y2 + x1 * x2 * (x1 - x2) * y3) / denom;

        xv = -B / (2 * A);
        yv = C - B * B / (4 * A);
    }
```

Knowing the parabolas y = ax2 + bx + c how do I code the rotation of this parabola?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Quetion is quite unclear. What are axes directions? (If you use gravity). How parabola is defined? Around what should it be rotated? Code piece is intended to find "top point" of 2d parabola - how is it related?

Comment: My apologies for not being clear enough. The ball moves through 3D space but its sideways velocity is comparable to the horizontal component of velocity of a 2D parabola in that it has a initial velocity and then a force acts over time and it intercepts x at the max range of the projectile. In the above script the doubles A, B and C are the parts a, b and c in a y = ax2 + bx + c quadratic equation. The parabola always origins at (0,0) and I would like to rotate it around the origin.

Comment: Rotate around the origin - in OXY plane?

Comment: Yes, in the OXY plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: simple method appropriate for vector drawing:

Generate points for usual parabola and rotate them around origin:

```
for x with some step:
    y = a * x*x + b *x + c
    rx = x * cos(phi) - y * sin(phi)
    ry = x * sin(phi) + y * cos(phi)
    draw line to rx,ry
```

Delphi code:

```
 var
  aa, bb, cc, y: Double;
  Phi, cs, sn: Double;
  X, xx, yy: Integer;
begin
  X := -300;
  aa := 0.01;
  bb := 0;
  cc := 0;
  Phi := -Pi/4;
  cs := Cos(Phi);
  sn := Sin(Phi);

  while X <= 200 do begin
     y := aa * x * x + bb * x + cc * x;
     xx := Round(200 + x * cs - y * sn);   //+200 to draw in visible region
     yy := Round(200 + x * sn + y * cs);
     if x = -200 then
        Canvas.MoveTo(xx, yy)
     else
        Canvas.LineTo(xx, yy);
     X := X + 10;
  end;
```

---

Note that rotated parabola cannot more be expressed as `Y(x)` function (imagine parabola rotated by 90 degrees)

General equation of quadratic curve is

```
 A*x^2 + B*x*y + C*y^2 + D*x + E*y + F = 0
```

In your case

```
 A = a; B,C=0; D=b; E=-1; F=c
```

The same general equation in matrix form
(reference: `Rogers, Adams. Mathematical elements for computer graphics` book)

```
           |A     B/2   D/2 |    |x|
 |x y 1| * |B/2   C     E/2 | *  |y| = 0
           |D/2   E/2   F   |    |1|
```

or using our coefficients

```
           |a     0     b/2 |    |x|
 |x y 1| * |0     0    -1/2 | *  |y| = 0
           |b/2  -1/2   c   |    |1|
```

To make rotation, we have to multiply central matrix by rotation matrix at the left and by transposed rotation matrix at the right and get final equation.
Here `cs=Cos(Phi)` and `sn=Sin(Phi)`

```
           |cs  -sn  0 |    |a     0     b/2 |    |cs  sn  0 |   |x|
 |x y 1| * |sn  cs   0 | *  |0     0    -1/2 |  * |-sn cs  0 | * |y| = 0
           |0   0    1 |    |b/2  -1/2   c   |    |0    0  1 |   |1|
```

If you have some instruments for symbolic calc like Maple, Matematica etc, you can multiply these matrices and get result. It is possible also to obtain it with pen and paper.

Edit: made Maple multiplication
[image]

Last expression in text:

```
 (((x*cs+y*sn)*a+1/2*b)*cs+1/2*sn)*x+
 (((x*cs+y*sn)*a+1/2*b)*sn-1/2*cs)*y+
 1/2*(x*cs+y*sn)*b+1/2*x*sn-1/2*y*cs+c
```

Collecting coefficients for x and y, we obtain coefficients of general equation

```
A = cs * cs * a 
B = 2 * a * cs * sn
C = sn * sn * a
D = cs * b + sn
E = sn * b - cs
F = c
```

Proof of concept: Delphi code generates parabola rotated by 45

```
var
  aa, bb, cc, A, B, C, d, E, F: Double;
  Phi, cs, sn: Double;
  X, Y: Integer;
begin
  aa := 0.01;
  bb := 0;
  cc := 0;
  Phi := -Pi / 4;
  cs := Cos(Phi);
  sn := Sin(Phi);
  A := cs * cs * aa;
  B := 2 * aa * cs * sn;
  C := sn * sn * aa;
  d := cs * bb + sn;
  E := sn * bb - cs;
  F := cc;
  for Y := -300 to 300 do
    for X := -300 to 300 do
      if Abs(A * X * X + B * X * Y + C * Y * Y + d * X + E * Y + F) <= 3 then
        Canvas.Pixels[X + 300, Y + 300] := clRed;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! The last part where you have drawn it using delphi is particularly helpful as I am using unity to draw it at the moment. Im trying to convert it to C# but am having some issues. If I understand correctly aa, bb, and cc are the values of a quadratic equation (y = aax2+ bbx + cc)? I think the trouble im having is converting the do loop at the bottom to a for loop for c#. If you know how to do that could you help? Otherwise thanks again, you have been of much help!

Comment: `y = aa*x2+ bb*x + cc` - yes. Loop is equivalent to `for(int y=-300; y<301; y++)` This image shows points that are close to parabola. It is hard to convert such image to vector drawing.  I added another method for this purpose

Comment: So I did do the correct translation to c# in the first place and now the <=3 in the for loop makes more sense in that its plotting points close to the parabola function. Is the vector drawing function you write of the 'ddd' function with variables x, y, cn = cos(theta), sn = sin(theta)?  What would the output be? It would only be one value right?

Comment: Vector drawing is alternate way - calculate points of basic parabola and rotate them.

Comment: I added code for simple drawing. Note - it is enough to draw curve. My first approach was to provide equation.